# How to load a .aspx page into contentplaceholder dynamically without postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I wanted to load a .aspx page into contentplaceholder without making a postback. What I have is a master page with 3 contentplaceholders

1.headerContent
2.leftContent
3.mainContent

I have 3 links in the headercontent and according to the selection of those 3 links, i'm showing few menu's on the leftcontent. On selecting any of the loaded menu on the left content i wanted to show/load a .aspx page inside the "maincontent" through the codebehind(C#), without making a refresh or postback. The .aspx pages which i wanted to load aren't inheriting the masterpage.

Other than using Iframes, is there any way to accomplish this??

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is to use user controls (.ascx) instead of pages. Have one page that loads all the controls from the start, this page will use the master page and will have its content place holder as the mainContent.

You can have each control inside a div on the page, and set the display of the div to none. Then you can use java script to display just the relevant user control.

Comment: so does that mean we cant load a page into <div> other than having it as a user control?